# RegEx to get path of file, without domain

Tags: vb.net, regex

I'm new to regular expressions, and have no clue where to start, it's like a diff language to me.  But I need one quick to accomplish a task.

I need to take

```
http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/file_path.txt
```

and get just

```
/folder1/folder2/file_path.txt
```

from it.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a lot simpler to do without regex; is regex a requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

construct a URI object from it and one of the properties of it will have what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think that regex should work:

```
^http://.*?/(.*)$
```

(tested with Python)

Answer (score 0):

Since VB.NET is in the tag for this question, I assume you have access at the server side to the Request object:

```
Dim instance As HttpRequest
Dim value As String

value = instance.Path
```

This should give you exactly what you asked for.

---

**Edit:** On second thought - you could be parsing URLs from some input string... in which case, regex will only help if you have a simple (regular) set of inputs:

Do you know all the possible domains? i.e. are "http://www.ABC.com" and "http://www.DEF.com" the only possible domains?

Then here:

```
Dim text As String = "http://www.ABC.com/folder1/folder2/file.txt"
Dim pattern As String = "(?:http://www.ABC.com|http://www.DEF.com)(.*)"

Dim r As Regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

' Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
Dim m As Match = r.Match(text)
Dim g as Group = m.Groups(2)  'Gives the string matched by the capturing parentheses
```

Answer (score 0):

Supporting more protocols and making the protocol optional too.

```
((https?|ftp)://)?(.*?)/(.*)
```